# Failed to install meego sdk 1.2 in Fedora13

Tags: linux, fedora, meego

After I downloaded meego sdk 1.2 from http://developer.meego.com/meego-sdk, the installation failed with the following error message:

```
 /home/ovilia/.config/meego.com/sdk/tm/_create_target.sh:h  
 line 34: /usr/bin/mad: No such file or directory
```

My system is fedora 13 (32 bit), and it seems to work fine as described in document.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the documentation ... Ana have you made the directory where you are installing and checked whether it is accessible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/mad` is a command line utility for renaming/moving files, provided by package `mmv`. To install the package, run as root:

```
yum install mmv
```